# If ${a_n}$ is a null sequence show that ${(a_n)^p}$ for all $p > 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a null sequence and $a_n > 0$. Use the definition of a
null sequence to prove that

(i) $(a_n^p)$ is null for all p > 0,

(ii) $(a_n^p)$  is not null for all $p \le 0$

(b) Show that if a sequence $(a_n)$ converges, any other sequence $(a_n)$ which
differs from $(a_n)$ only by a finite number of terms also converges, and with
the same limit.

I understand why a null sequence raised to a power still converges to 0 for $p>0$ and why it doesn't for $p \le 0$,but I am having trouble proving it.

And for part $(b)$ I don't know where to begin

Comment: You can find an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, and any $\epsilon>0$, $|a_n|<\epsilon^{\frac{1}{p}}$. What does this tell you about $|a_n|^p$?

Comment: @Loobear23 that $|a_n|^p$ < $ϵ$, which means it is null?